# How do I remove Mercurial .HG folder from project but still keep it under source control?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and
I noticed when I published my project that all the files in the published directory were also under source control which I don't want. When I looked at one of my other projects under source control I noticed it didn't have the `.hg folder` and publishes without issue. I then removed the `.hg folder` and I was able to build and publish and the files were no longer under source control BUT now my project isn't either.
I put back the `.hg folder` and I'm back where I started. **How do I remove the .hg folder from my project but still retain source control?**

Answer (score 3):

The `.hg` directory cannot be removed. It contains everything Mercurial knows about your project. Deleting that directory effectively removes all source control.

Add files you don't want to be tracked to the `.hgignore` file in the root of your repository instead. See the [`hgignore` documentation](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) for the format of this file.

Comment: Actually it can be removed, but as you said and I mentioned in my original question was that I wanted to retain source control. hgignore does not appear to work on folders but only files. As it turns out I moved the .hg folder outside my project folder instead of in the project folder which solved my issue.

Comment: @Gregg, How could you do this? can you put your answer, that can help people like me.

Comment: @YellowandRed: Gregg is just moving the `.hg` folder somewhere else then back again, because at the time it appears he did not understand how `.hgignore` works. That doesn't make it a good idea however! You can add directories to `.hgignore` just fine, but without more information I can't help.

Comment: It’s been awhile since this occurred so I’m fuzzy on the details, I didn’t just move the hg folder and back again as Martijn suggested. I moved it completely outside my project folder, the issue I was having in my initial post was resolved.

Comment: @Gregg: yes, but at that point your whole project is no longer under mercurial management, and the paths that are recorded in the `.hg` directory no longer can be found in relation to that folder. It is never a good idea.

Comment: Again it's been too long but I don't think I would have considered that a solution if I hadn't still been under Mercurial management. I'm not suggesting this as a solution for anyone, best to probably just close the thread.